# Tie Android fingerprint to Already created User Login

Tags: android, authentication, android-fingerprint-api, gigya

I want to add in fingerprint login to my app.  We have two was of logging in one being with email and pwd and the other is through gigya FB.  I want to be able to tie in the fingerprint to login into either one of these login methods and fire off the login.  If anyone has the ADT Pulse app they seem to be able to do this.

I have all the hardware in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint"
    android:required="false"/>
```

I have taken a look at how to access the fingerprint manager.  Just need to figure out how to tie that to my apps login or gigya FB login

Comment: SO I have worked on this some and apparently you need to first store the login info and let the user select an option to use fingerprint to login.  Then you have to enable the scanner in your app, pull the login crendentials and send them to your login API service.

Answer (score 0):

Gigya doesn't currently support Fingerprint ID, it is on our roadmap. If you are a customer, you can ask your account manager to add a vote to the feature for you.

Comment: So at the very least how can I tie the fingerprint to a login.  I can't seem to find what I'm looking for on any of the examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as Apple and Google do not provide fingerprint data.